# How to create grayscale CGImage from iPhone Camera?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, avfoundation

I want to create grayscale CGImage from iPhones camera data. I'm using AVFoundation and set pixel format type to

```
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
```

If I understand correctly I should be able to create grayscale image from Y component so I have implemented delegate method like this:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
        let yPlanBufferAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)

        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)        

        let data = NSData(bytes: yPlanBufferAddress, length: width * height)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data)
        let imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width * 8, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrderDefault, dataProvider, nil, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)
        let img = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
        delegate?.cameraController(self, didCreateImage: img)
    }
```

but I'm getting strange images like this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I found one bug - in function CGImageCreate there shouldn't be width * 8 as parameter for bytesForRow - simply width. But even after fixing that my image looks like this: http://zapodaj.net/409d6abaaecd5.png.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must get 'bytesPerRow' for the Y plane, and supply it to CGImageCreate.

```
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane( w, 0 );

let imageRef = CGImageCreate(
    width
,   height
,   8
,   8
,   bytesPerRow
```

Answer (score -1):

Previously, I have used a framework called [GPU Image by BradLarson](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), pretty amazing one, to make custom filters. They have some predefined filters too, which can be used. Works pretty fast.

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to create a grayscale image is to use a `CIFliter`like this, just play with the values to get the desired level of effect. You can also put several filter in series to have even more control over things like contrast, exposure, color, etc.

```
+ (UIImage *)makeBW:(UIImage *)imageToConvert
{
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageToConvert CGImage]];

    CIImage *blackAndWhite = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"
                                        keysAndValues:
                              kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,
                              @"inputBrightness", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                              @"inputContrast", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.12],
                              @"inputSaturation", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], nil].outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage];

    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

    return newImg;
}
```

Comment: But the grayscale values should be the same as Y component, right? So i don't have to do any filtering, just create image from this values. Beside this are you sure the result of filter will be in grayscale - 8 bit per pixel?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I'm not a video expert, I have just always used the CIFilter to get the effect.

Comment: Found this info:  One of two primary color spaces used to represent digital component video (the other is RGB). The difference between YCbCr and RGB is that YCbCr represents color as brightness and two color difference signals, while RGB represents color as red, green and blue. In YCbCr, the Y is the brightness (luma), Cb is blue minus luma (B-Y) and Cr is red minus luma (R-Y). See component video.

Comment: Yes, thats why I have set pixel format to kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange. Grayscale represents only brightness, so I should be able to create image using only Y component bud don't know whats wrong.